# unable to track migration in subfolders in django

Tags: django

in Django when I am running this command python 'manage.py makemigrations  Planning' it is saying no change detect and it also not creating any pycache folder in that subfolder.

but when I am creating the model in another subfolder on which I had worked in past then it works properly, I am unable to understand what's going on. please healp

Comment: show your settings.py code

Comment: The argument to `makemigrations` isn't a directory name - it is the `name` of the app for which you want to make migrations. Most likely there is no app in your project called `Planning`. You'll need to post your directory structure and list of installed apps for further help.